# Attribute Routing in WebAPI: The Resource Cannot Be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

ASP.NET MVC4 Project with WebAPI endpoints.  I'm trying to configure AR for both MVC Controllers and API controllers.  I added the following:

[image]

And now I see two more files in App_Start: AttributeRoutingConfig, and AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.

The first has this:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AttributeRoutingConfig), "Start")]

public static class AttributeRoutingConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
    {       
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
    public static void Start() 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

The second has this:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AttributeRoutingHttpConfig), "Start")]

public static class AttributeRoutingHttpConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routes) 
    {    
        routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
    public static void Start() 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes);
    }
}
```

In my GlobalConfig I have this:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

In my WebApiConfig I have this:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

The error I get when I try to POST to a route decorated with [POST("api/message")]:

```
The constraint entry 'inboundHttpMethod' on the route with route template 'api/message' must have a string value or be of a type which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'.
```

In my Global.asax:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to combine Tim McCall's package + Web API 2's built-in Attribute routing feature. Do not install the package as its already built into Web API 2 version.

Check this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks Kiran - I'll try to pull the packages and see what happens.  Do I still need the MVC Attribute Routing package since I'm on MVC4?

Comment: Cool.  I replaced my attributes with [Route()] after removing the WebApi package and all seems ok - though it stinks that I can't specify POST anymore

Comment: just add HttpPost to the route: [Route(""), HttpPost()]